# Set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header in a controller action (CORS issues)

Tags: modules, controller, headers

I send a POST request from a headless frontend to a craft controller action but the request is not going trough because of:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localcraft.ddev.site/add-comment. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

(I set a custom route in routes.php, so I can reach the action via `/add-comment`).

I think I have to do something with `$response = Craft::$app->getResponse();`
But I can't figure out what.

I also set this at the beginning of my controller:

```
class AddToQueueController extends Controller
{
    protected array|bool|int $allowAnonymous = ["add-comment"];
    public $enableCsrfValidation = !["add-comment"];
```

But that does not help either...

I am glad for any help!
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Ok I realized that this works:

```php
$response = Craft::$app->getResponse();
$response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

But somehow my axios POST request still has CORS preflight issue, although I can see the headers set in Insomnia...

I have to look for the actual problem now.

=====================
Edit:
Well together with Chat GPT I found out that I kind of need to return the response early for an OPTIONS request. So the CORS preflight gets the headers.

```php
$response = Craft::$app->getResponse();

$response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
$response->headers->set(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
);
$response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
$response->headers->set("Content-Type", "application/json");

if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getMethod() === "OPTIONS") {
    // for CORS preflight we need to return the request early.
    return $response;
}
```

I don't fully understand, why I need to do that specifically, but somehow these headers are missing if I don't.
I also can't really imagine that this is not a more commonly met problem... and not documented here already...

Anyway, I hope this helps somebody one day.
Cheers